# Change auto-binding template from element using Polymer

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

```
<template is="dom-bind" id="app">
  <div>{{title}}</div>
  <my-element></my-element>
</template>
```

Can I inside `my-element` force the auto-bind template to redraw?

I can get the template, but changing it does not trigger a redraw:

```
var app = document.querySelector('#app');
app.title = 'Zaphod';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should work, except setting the `title` needs to wait until *polymer* is ready (i.e. elements have been registered and are ready to be interacted with).

```
var app = document.querySelector('#app');

document.addEventListener("WebComponentsReady", function () {
    app.title = 'Zaphod';
});
```

Comment: You were right, my code worked. My problem was elsewhere, your answer helped me get there though. Thanx